# Agregar objetos a un array de objetos

Tags: php

Estoy creando el siguiente array de objetos en php

```
$resultado = array('id' => $total[$i]->id_usuario, 'nombre' => $total[$i]->nombre, 'codigo' => $total[$i]->codigo, 'concepto' => " ", 'horas_no_cargables' => " ");
```

Me gustaria a ese array agregando mas datos a medida de que me van llegando. probe con el push pero creo que no lo permite, lo tengo de la siguiente manera. Me dice que los {} no van y si se los quito me dice, (T_DOUBLE_ARROW).

```
array_push($resultado, {'id' => $id_usuario, 'nombre' => "", 'codigo' => "", 'concepto' => $concepto, 'horas_no_cargables' => $horas_no_cargables});
```

Comment: Hola. En lugar de usar las llaves `{}` intenta usando `array()`.

Comment: Pero... Por lo que planteas en el ejemplo $total ya es un array de objetos... Y lo que estás haciendo es asignar un array asociativo a una variable... No será que quieres ir añadiendo arrays a esa variable? Si es así, entonces con que al lado izquierdo de la asignación  pongas $resultado[] = .. ya lo tendrías.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrégalos sin las llaves y con array() solo que es necesario agregar [ ] a la variable $resultado

```
$resultado[] = array('id' => $total[$i]->id_usuario, 'nombre' => $total[$i]->nombre, 'codigo' => $total[$i]->codigo, 'concepto' => " ", 'horas_no_cargables' => " ");
    
array_push($resultado, array('id' => $id_usuario, 'nombre' => "", 'codigo' => "", 'concepto' => $concepto, 'horas_no_cargables' => $horas_no_cargables));
```